# Simple query and error on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with CodeIgniter and Mysql. I am getting an error with a very simple query:

```
$o = "INSERT INTO usuarios (user, password) VALUES ('deesggsd', 'dsggd')";
$query = $this->db->query($o);
$this->db->query($query);
```

produces:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

1

Filename: C:\wamp\www\newWeb\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

But the query is actually executed; the row appears on the database. What i'm doind wrong?

If I execute the same query on phpmyadmin, all is ok.

Thanks!!!

Comment: why 2 "$this->db->query"?

Comment: That's soooooooooooooooooooo **"no time to read manuals"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing with `$query = $this->db->query($o);` is executing the query and storing the result to the `$query` variable. So you've already run the `INSERT` once which is why it stores properly to the database.

Now when you try to run `$this->db->query($query);` you're basically trying to run a mysql procedure using the result (TRUE) as your query string. This is where it throws the error. Make sense?

Try doing this instead:

```
$this->db->insert('usuarios', array(
    'user'     => 'deesggsd',
    'password' => 'dsggd'
);
```

I suggest looking into [Active Record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) and how interaction between PHP & mysql work in general. No offense but this is a beginner level mistake.

Comment: That sir is a question that you and only you can answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use activer recored it's sample and easy,

that will be solve your problem

```
$values = array('user'=>'deesggsd', 'password'=> 'dsggd');  
$this->db->insert('usuarios',$values)
```

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html